# Comprehensive database of cell types

Tags: cell-biology, database

Wondering if there is a comprehensive list/database of cell types, similar to [this wiki list of cell types in the human body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distinct_cell_types_in_the_adult_human_body). It lists probably 100+ different types, but this is just for a human. If we include all animals, and plants, and bacteria, and single celled organisms, etc. then the list would probably get larger.

Wondering if any such aggregation exists, either just as a collection of lists or as a database of cell types. Doing a search returns [CELLPEDIA](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22039163), but the last results are from 2011, so it looks like it never came to be. I also saw MorphoBase, but it didn't look like it was there either. But something like that would be good, otherwise just a list. Basically like a cell taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

A currently active cell database is [SHOGoiN](http://shogoin.stemcellinformatics.org/), which says it is a significant extension of the world-first human cell database, CELLPEDIA.  It focuses on human cells but also has information on mouse, sea urchin, and *C. elegans*.

The site says:

> The database consists of several modules that store cell lineage maps, transcriptome, methylome, cell conversions, cell type markers, and cell images with morphology data curated from public as well as contracted resources, based on sophisticated cell taxonomy.

Comment: Wondering if you know of anything similar for plants/bacteria/single-celled organisms.